# How to debug SWC components in Flash pro?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swc, jsfl

I have complied my components into SWC and add it in Flash professional.

If I want debug this SWC components, how to do this ? `trace()` and `MMExecute()` seems invalid.

Thanks!

Comment: Components are not meant to be debuged they are compiled/packaged. The only way to debug it would be to work from the source code that was used to compile/package it.

Comment: @The_asMan I have source code and how to debug?

Comment: You run the source code without making it a component

Comment: remove the component from your library to do this

Comment: @The_asMan I use the SWC in edit mode not runtime.I don't play swf at all :-)

Comment: My point is there should be no SWC. You include the source files into your library not the SWC

Comment: @The_asMan I use SWC because I want seen the changes when I changing the property of it. Only including source files into my library can do this function?

Comment: yes you can only debug from the source files

Answer (score 0):

you can say that SWC is one type of executable file of your library. it is generated after compiling the library(source code) and compiler removes all trace, comments and minimize the swc file size . so f you want to know about how's execution is going on in swc component. you have to implement log in it. to write a log, follow the step

1. create a private variable in application

`private var _fs:FileStream = new FileStream();`

1. put this in close handler of application.

`protected function windowedapplication1_closeHandler(event:Even`t):void`

`{`

`var prefsFile:File = File.desktopDirectory;`

`prefsFile = prefsFile.resolvePath("logfile.txt");`

```
    fs.open(prefsFile,FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeUTFBytes(logString);
    fs.close();
}`
```

3.Make another variable named logString, and contact string as you want to put a log

Example of this:

`logString += 'onAttitones_creationCompleteHandler'+'\n';`

this will write a logfile in desktop, file Name is logfile.txt

may this will help you

Comment: I'm not using AIR.The filestream package is unavailable.

Comment: this will help you
http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/20/reading-and-writing-local-files-in-flash-player-10/

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your compiled components by passing custom logger in them. Create interface ILoggable with only 2 methods: `setLogger(logger: ILogger)` and `log(value: *)`. Implement interface in desired components.

```
public function log(value:*):void{
    if(_logger != null){
        _logger.log(value);
    }
}

public function setLogger(logger:ILogger):void {
    _logger= logger;
}
```

Now you are free to use `log(something)` in every interesting place of your component, but don't forget to assign logger:

```
//Create logger
logger = new TraceLogger();
//...
//Use it somewhere with components, that can produce logs
myComponent = new MyComponent();
myComponent.setLogger(logger);
```

Declare your epic trace logger somewhere in project:

```
public class TraceLogger implements ILogger{
    public function log(value:*):void{
        trace(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by `myComponent = new MyComponent();`.The swc is used in Flash pro.I don't play an swf. So I don't know how to place the TraceLogger. :-)

Comment: So you work with Flash without compiling your project to get some result?